# Read CSV file that was exported from MongoDB in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, csv

I am working for hours on loading a CSV file into Python using the well-known `pd.read_csv('..')`

However, there is a problem:

```
Error message : Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3991 fields in line 14, saw 4572
```

But yes, my code is without mistakes.

The CSV looks like this..

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5cf683d88eb9ad12c84f6469"},"ID":"22991137","name":"M. LundstrÃ¶
```

Maybe the problem occurs because MongoDB is using strict BSON formats, but honestly - I do not know anything about that.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Sorry, Error Code is this : ** : Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3991 fields in line 14, saw 4572**

Comment: Have you checked what is wrong in line 14? Did you use mongoexport ?

Also, give this a try: `pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=",", encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: I think you shouldn't try to load a json file using read_csv. Have you already tried `pandas.io.json.json_normalize`? See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

Comment: The point is, that in a json file fields, that are not filled are normally omitted, while in a csv file they have to be present and also the order plays no role in json while in csv it's important.

Comment: Are you able to use something like `pastebin` to provide a link to the whole file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pd.read_csv() only on a csv file. However the format looks like invalid JSON to me(parenthesis not closed).

You need to export this way for mongodb -

```
mongoexport --db dbname --collection col --type=csv --fields _id,field1,feild2 --out outfile.csv
```

EDIT:

if you want to read the JSON file only, you may read it like this -

```
import json

with open('filepath', 'rb') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)
```